# chrono on Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, c++-chrono

I am working with Visual Studio 2005 (I can't use a newer version because they are not compatible with the old haptic interface I am using). I need to use the library "chrono", but I can't seem to include it. The error *Cannot open include file: 'chrono': No such file or directory* appears on the line `#include <chrono>`

I tested using chrono on Visual Studio 2012 (on the same computer) and it worked fine. How do I get it to work on my Visual Studio 2005?

I am not an expert programmer, the solution might be basic.

Please no suggestions about just using VS12, trust me I tried!

Comment: `<chrono>` became part of the C++ standard in 2011.  VS-2005 was shipped in, well, 2005.  `<chrono>` wasn't even invented until 2008: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) includes a [`chrono` library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/chrono.html) (officially released in version 1.47.0), which can be used as an alternative to C++11's `chrono` library for older compiler versions which do not fully support C++11 (including Visual Studio versions older than VS2012).

Answer (score 0):

If you go on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874757.aspx, you'll see that it doesn't work with version of VS under 2012.